# find patterns in digraphs

Tags: java, algorithm, digraphs

I'm trying to write simple code in java to find patterns (understood as recurrent sequence of elements in a superstructure)  in  digraphs (DAG) random generated.
I know for example the K-recurring substring to identify pattern but are there other known techniques?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like algorythmic question rather that design-patterns. You would get more if repost it on the Computer Science.